# i2c : When writing to Slave Read 255 seen on bus

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, error, read

I am using Renesas RH850 controller in which I am writing 48 byte of data to slave device (Ublox IC) over i2c every 100ms and sometimes I can see 255 in between my data transfer which results in failure of transmission.

What is the reason in which I am seeing this issue. Am I missing something in i2c protocol ?

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your basis for the idea that this is supposed to yield some other result?  Do you see different results with these operations at times?  What is the nature of the operation you are conducting when this happens, and what are the variety of ways in which the target device is documented to respond?  Eg, if it has no more data to give you, is this a legitimate response?  Or in getting this far, have you already ignored (or failed to check) some status required _before_ attempting this read?

Comment: The protocol already goes wrong before that. There is a stop condition on the bus before it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : Here I still want to send 46 byte of data, total of 48 byte of data packet which I am writing to slave. Only I am the master on bus. Target slave device I am not sure as do not have document for the same. Master is not reading any thing from slave here.

Comment: @Justme : Yes. what could have happened which caused this issue. is only master can generate stop signal on bus or slave has gone out of sink here ?

Comment: Impossible to say why that happens. It could be hardware issue. Or software issue. On either device. You don't give us anything we could base a specific answer.